# Can I use any DIY hubs with Lutron Caseta?

Tags: home-automation

I'm interested in the Lutron Caseta (or frankly any other wifi compatible dimmer switch that works with LEDs). But I'm NOT interested in adding YAPH (Yet Another Proprietary Hub) to my already overloaded network. I already run a server or two on my network full time. So I would love to be able to "emulate" the hub from my server. Anyone done this or heard about others doing this?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. This may be off-topic for our Home Improvement site, due to it's electronics focus.

Comment: I tend to agree that you will be more likely to get a useful answer if you talk to wireless network geeks rather than Home Improvement geeks. This needs a fair amount of tech savvy.

Comment: Perhaps you should look at an existing home automation network technology?

Answer (score 2):

The Lutron Caséta Wireless product line isn't the best line for your needs. Yes, you will need a Lutron Smart Bridge or a Lutron Smart Bridge Pro to communicate with your Caséta Wireless devices. It is made to be end user friendly (idiot proof) to the point of not being DIY automation friendly.

Lutron hasn't published their API software publicly, but there is a PDF of their [intergration protocol](http://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/040249.pdf) available. This PDF outlines Lutron's five product families that are their professional residential/commercial solutions ([QS Standalone](http://www.lutron.com/en-US/Products/Pages/WholeHomeSystems/Homeworksqs/Components.aspx) / [Quantum](http://www.lutron.com/en-US/Products/Pages/WholeBuildingSystems/Quantum/Components.aspx) / [RadioRA 2](http://www.lutron.com/en-US/Products/Pages/WholeHomeSystems/RadioRA2/Components.aspx) / [HomeWorks QS](http://www.lutron.com/en-US/Products/Pages/WholeHomeSystems/Homeworksqs/Components.aspx) / [myRoom plus](http://www.lutron.com/en-US/Products/Pages/SingleRoomControls/myRoom/Components.aspx)), and explains how to connect and send automation commands over ethernet (TCP/IP) or serial (RS-232) to each of them. Unfortunately, you'll still need to purchase a proprietary Lutron Integration Access Point for whichever product line you choose. The Integration Access Point is necessary to transmit the TCP/IP or RS-232 communications from your computer to the wireline or RF frequency the Lutron device can communicate on, but it's not as bad as adding another proprietary smart hub that tries to run everything in your house for you.

If you absolutely don't want to add another proprietary hub or don't want to limit yourself to a specific brand, then it might be better to go with a brand/protocol that easily communicates with your computer and isn't brand specific. A product that uses [Z-Wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-Wave), [X10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X10_(industry_standard)), or [Zigbee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zigbee) might be better for you, and should be supported longer than any of Lutron's lines.